# Aspect ratio in Live-Charts

Tags: c#, wpf, dynamic-data-display, livecharts

I've been using for a while the "dynamic-data-display" library, but there are not many examples and some things are a bit difficult to accomplish. I've found the "Live charts" library and I really like its simplicity.

What happens is that there is a feature that I can't find. In "dynamic-data-display" library, called "PhysicalProportionsConstraint", but here I can't find anything like that. It serves to make if I represent, for example, a polygon, a square for example, do not appear deformed never when I make zoom or pan.

Thanks a lot. Let's see if someone can help me.